# Is there a way to use setters instead of animations in a storyboard?

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, setter

Animations are nice, but sometimes I just want to change the value of a property instantly, without any animation. Apparently, the only way to do that is to use a `<Something>AnimationUsingKeyFrames`:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtStatus" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

The syntax is a mess... 7 lines of code just to set a property to a different value?!

Is there a simpler way?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<Storyboard>
    <Setter TargetName="txtStatus" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Storyboard>
```

(I know this code isn't valid, it's just to give an example of what I'd like)

---

EDIT: just to make things clear: I know about `Triggers` and `DataTriggers`, but they're not what I need, because they can only be used in styles and control templates. I'm using the `VisualStateManager` in a `UserControl`, so I'm forced to use a `Storyboard`.

Comment: see triggers here after quick look around :



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535671/wpf-triggers

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a non-keyframe animation for the type of the property that you're setting (and there are a whole bunch of non-keyframe animation types), you can use an animation with a Duration of 0.  This has the effect of acting like a setter and in one line of xaml.  For example:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtStatus" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Value="Red" Duration="0" />
</Storyboard>
```

This works because the default FillBehavior of the animation is HoldEnd.

It's not quite the same as having the word "Setter" appear -- browsing the xaml requires some interpretation to realize that the animation has the effect of an instantaneous set.  Also, the value will revert when the storyboard ends, but this does fit the bill for changing a value instantly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I know I can do that, but ideally I'd like a more generic solution...

Comment: In what way are you looking for it to be more generic?

Comment: Well, first of all, not all properties can be animated with a non-keyframe animation. For instance, I often want to set a different brush (rather that the color of the brush), and there is no BrushAnimation. And the syntax is still a bit clumsy, and I have to use different animations for each type of property

Comment: In that case, no, there's not a simpler way.  The Children of a Storyboard all must be some sort of Timeline.  The only option for which you can specify any type of property is ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames (with it's bloated syntax).  All options are idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to set up triggers (Which you probably already have to call the storyboards. Rather than filling them with `BeginStoryboard` and `Storyboard` items you fill them with setters.

```
<Trigger Property="<SomeProperty>" Value="<SomeValue>">
   <Setter TargetName="txtStatus" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have been more specific about my problem. I know about Triggers, but they're not what I need. They can only be used in a Style or ControlTemplate. I'm looking for something I can use with the VisualStateManager, which is why I have a Storyboard.